# Can I change the local nodeos blocktime?

Tags: nodeos

I want to change the existing block-time (0.5 sec) to a specific value.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would edit this value:

```
const static int      block_interval_ms = 500;
```

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/75635168e743c3e65bb6345a1eaedd905581e6b0/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/config.hpp#L42